# Plotshape for only one ticker. Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

I want to do a plot shape of LONG and SHORT for only SPY ticker. I do not want it to show for other tickers should not show. I have already request security for the SPY only. But, it is also showing LONG and SHORT for other tickers. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `syminfo.ticker` to check if your chart is on `SPY`.

> Symbol name without exchange prefix, e.g. 'MSFT'.

```
is_spy = (syminfo.ticker == "SPY")
```

Then use `is_spy` as a condition to your `plotshape()` functions.

Comment: plotshape(not confirmLONG1[1] and confirmLONG1, title='Buy Label', style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.normal, text='LONG 1 ', textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), color=color.new(color.green, 0))

Comment: Where should I put it?

Comment: To your `series` argument.